# I'm getting a segmentation fault in my assembly program

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

This is my first time using assembly. When I run the program I get this error:

```
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./t
```

I believe the issue is it's trying to access (or execute) memory that it's not allowed to.

As I said, this is my first time and don't know where the issue would be. Thanks!

Here's the command I'm running it with:

```
nano -c t.asm && nasm -f elf32 t.asm && ld -melf_i386 -s -o t t.o && ./t
```

And here is `t.asm`:

```
; This is a simple program to read through a file and output vowels
; to stderr, and constants to stdout.

global _start

section .text

_start:
        mov eax, 0x5  ; open
        mov ebx, file ; filename
        mov ecx, 0x1  ; read only
        int 0x80      ; syscall

        bufferloop:
                mov ebx, eax      ; file descriptor from open
                mov eax, 0x3      ; read
                mov ecx, inbuffer ; buffer
                mov edx, 1024     ; buffer size
                int 0x80          ; syscall

                cmp eax, 0 ; compare read count to 0
                je done    ; read count is 0, done

                mov ecx, 0 ; index 0
                compareloop:
                        mov ebx, [inbuffer + ecx] ; value at index of array

                        mov edx, 0 ; index 0
                        vowelloop:
                                mov esi, [vowels + edx] ; value at index of vowels

                                cmp ebx, esi ; compare value to this vowel
                                je isvowel   ; is vowel

                                ; not this vowel
                                inc edx             ; incremnt index
                                cmp edx, vowels_len ; compare index to vowel count
                                jl vowelloop        ; loop

                        isconstant: ; not jumped, but hey
                        mov edi, cbuffer
                        add edi, cfilled
                        mov [edi], ebx ; add to array
                        inc dword [cfilled]                ; incrment array "index"

                        cmp dword [cfilled], 1024 ; compare filled to buffer size
                        jne nowritec         ; write constants to output
                        call writec
                        nowritec:

                        jmp aftervowel ; skip vowel

                        isvowel:
                        mov edi, vbuffer
                        add edi, vfilled
                        mov [edi], ebx ; add to array
                        inc dword [vfilled]                ; incrment index

                        cmp dword [vfilled], 1024 ; compare filled to buffer size
                        jne nowritev         ; write vowels to output
                        call writev
                        nowritev:

                        aftervowel:
                        inc ecx
                        cmp ecx, eax ; compare current index to the buffer count
                        jl compareloop
                jmp bufferloop
        done:
        call writec
        call writev
        call exit

writec:
        pusha

        mov eax, 0x4       ; syscall write
        mov ebx, 1         ; stdout
        mov ecx, cbuffer   ; constants
        mov edx, [cfilled] ; size of buffer

        mov dword [cfilled], 0 ; reset index to 0

        popa
        ret

writev:
        pusha

        mov eax, 0x4       ; syscall write
        mov ebx, 2         ; stderr
        mov ecx, vbuffer   ; vowels
        mov edx, [vfilled] ; size of buffer

        mov dword [vfilled], 0 ; reset index to 0

        popa
        ret

file db "file.txt"

inbuffer times 1024 db 0

cbuffer times 1024 db 0
cfilled db 0

vbuffer times 1024 db 0
vfilled db 0

vowels db "AEIOUaeiou"
vowels_len equ $-vowels

exit:
        mov eax, 0x1
        int 0x80
        ret
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. From a quick glance, the problem is you put your variables in the `.text` section which is read-only. Put them in `.data` instead.

Comment: See also the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  Also, you use nano?  I find it way too limited compared to emacs.

Comment: Also, instead of looping over the string containing all vowels, check a bitmap in a register.  (First check that your input character is alphabetic and lowercase it, then subtract `'a'` to turn the ASCII encoding into a 0-25 index.  Use that with `bt reg, reg` to detect vowels.  See [my answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35936844/224132) for asm tricks for checking if a character is alphabetic, and downcasing it.)