# Passing string parameter to a PROC

Tags: windows, winapi, x86, masm

I want to call a function that will perform upper to lower case conversion to a user typed string, preserving the especial characters.  This part works, but only for the first 4 characters, everything after that just gets truncated.  I believe it is because I have defined the parameters as DWORD:

I have tried using `PAGE`, `PARA` and `BYTE`.  The first two don't work and with byte says type missmatch.

```
upperToLower proc, source:dword, auxtarget:dword
  mov eax, source       ;Point to string
  mov ebx, auxtarget     ; point to destination
  L1:
  mov dl, [eax]            ; Get a character from buffer
    cmp byte ptr [eax], 0                  ; End of string? (not counters)
    je printString             ; if true, jump to printString
    cmp dl, 65                 ; 65 == 'A'
    jl notUpper                ; if less, it's not uppercase
    cmp dl, 90                 ; 90 == 'Z'
    jg notUpper                ; if greater, it's not uppercase
    xor dl, 100000b            ; XOR to change upper to lower
    mov [ebx], dl      ; add char to target
    inc eax                    ; Move counter up
    inc ebx                    ; move counter up
    jmp L1                     ; loop

    notUpper:                  ; not uppercase
    mov [ebx], dl      ; copy the letter
    inc eax            ;next letter
    inc ebx
    jmp L1

    printString:
    invoke WriteConsoleA,   consoleOutHandle, auxtarget, sizeof auxtarget, bytesWritten,    0
    ret
upperToLower endp
```

The PROTO:

```
  upperToLower PROTO,
    source: dword,
    auxtarget: dword
```

Invoke:

```
    invoke upperToLower, offset buffer, offset target
```

The buffer parameter is: `buffer db 128 DUP(?)`

How can I get printed the whole string, and not just the first 4 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are only 4 characters being printed? You write the string to the console with:

```
invoke WriteConsoleA,   consoleOutHandle, auxtarget, sizeof auxtarget, bytesWritten,    0
```

The `sizeof auxtarget` parameter is the size of `auxtarget` which is a `DWORD` (4 bytes) thus you are asking to only print 4 bytes. You need to pass the length of the string. You can easily do so by taking the ending address in *EAX* and subtracting the `source` pointer from it. The result would be the length of the string you traversed.

Modify the code to be:

```
printString:
sub eax, source
invoke WriteConsoleA,   consoleOutHandle, auxtarget, eax, bytesWritten,    0
```

A version of your code that follows the *C* call convention, uses both a source and destination buffer, tests for the pointers to make sure they aren't NULL, does the conversion using a similar [method described by Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40372661/3857942) is as follows:

```
upperToLower proc uses edi esi, source:dword, dest:dword 
    ; uses ESI EDI is used to tell assembler we are clobbering two of
    ; the cdecl calling convetions non-volatile registers. See:
    ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl
    mov esi, source            ; ESI = Pointer to string
    test esi, esi              ; Is source a NULL pointer?
    jz done                    ;     If it is then we are done

    mov edi, dest              ; EDI = Pointer to string
    test edi, edi              ; Is dest a NULL pointer?
    jz done                    ;     If it is then we are done

    xor edx, edx               ; EDX = 0 = current character index into the strings

    jmp getnextchar            ; Jump into loop at point of getting next character

  charloop:
    lea ecx, [eax - 'A']       ; cl = al-'A', and we do not care about the rest
                               ;     of the register

    cmp cl, 25                 ; if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') c += 0x20;
    lea ecx, [eax + 20h]       ; without affecting flags
    cmovna eax, ecx            ; take the +0x20 version if it was in the 
                               ;     uppercase range to start with
    mov [edi + edx], al        ; Update character in destination string
    inc edx                    ; Go to next character

  getnextchar:
    movzx eax, byte ptr [esi + edx]
                               ; mov al, [esi + edx] leaving high garbage in EAX is ok
                               ;     too, but this avoids a partial-register stall
                               ;     when doing the mov+sub
                               ;     in one instruction with LEA
    test eax, eax              ; Is the character NUL(0) terminator?
    jnz charloop               ;     If not go back and process character

  printString:
    ; EDI = source, EDX = length of string

    invoke WriteConsoleA, consoleOutHandle, edi, edx, bytesWritten, 0
    mov edx, sizeof buffer
  done:
    ret
upperToLower endp
```

A version that takes one parameter and changes the source string to upper case could be done this way:

```
upperToLower proc, source:dword
    mov edx, source            ; EDX = Pointer to string
    test edx, edx              ; Is it a NULL pointer?
    jz done                    ;     If it is then we are done

    jmp getnextchar            ; Jump into loop at point of getting next character

  charloop:
    lea ecx, [eax - 'A']       ; cl = al-'A', and we do not care about the rest
                               ;     of the register

    cmp cl, 25                 ; if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') c += 0x20;
    lea ecx, [eax + 20h]       ; without affecting flags
    cmovna eax, ecx            ; take the +0x20 version if it was in the
                               ;     uppercase range to start with
    mov [edx], al              ; Update character in string
    inc edx                    ; Go to next character

  getnextchar:
    movzx eax, byte ptr [edx]  ; mov al, [edx] leaving high garbage in EAX is ok, too,
                               ;     but this avoids a partial-register stall 
                               ;     when doing the mov+sub in one instruction with LEA
    test eax, eax              ; Is the character NUL(0) terminator?
    jnz charloop               ;     If not go back and process character

  printString:
    sub edx, source            ; EDX-source=length
    invoke WriteConsoleA, consoleOutHandle, source, edx, bytesWritten, 0
  done:
    ret
upperToLower endp
```

---

### Observations

- A generic `upperToLower` function that does the string conversion would normally not do the printing itself. You'd normally call `upperToLower` to do the conversion only, then you'd output the string to the display in a separate call.

Comment: Could you please give me some guidance on how to make it more efficient?

Comment: @Wolfeius : I've provided a couple of examples in my latest update using a different technique

Comment: Thank you for that.  It will take me some time to understand everything that's going on, but I will try to use the few bits I think I got right in the next bits of this program.  Thanks!