# Write Assembly Code to Read a character, and if it's an uppercase letter, display it

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am new in Assembly Programming. I am trying to solve this simple code but emu8086 compiler showing error; I failed to run the program.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H  
.DATA
.CODE
MAIN PROC

    MOV AH,1
    INT 21H

    CMP AL,'Y'
    JE THEN
    CMP AL,'Y'  
    JE THEN
    JMP ELSE_
THEN:
    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,AL
    INT 21H
    JMP END_IF

ELSE_: 
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
END_IF:    

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: What error message did you get?  This isn't a [mcve].  (Also, `cmp`/`je` with the same compare twice is redundant.  You should just be skipping over print code if the input is below `'A'` or above `'Z'`.  Or signed less / greater if you want.

Comment: After `END_IF:` you have no code to properly exit the program.

Answer (score 1):

your code is close, not foo far from correct

first of all: your algorithm. you obviously copied this from something like a "yes/no" question, and didn't adjust the logic

what you want is:

```
get char
if ( char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ) 
then 
   display char
else 
   /* do nothing */
endif
```

since && in conditions in asm is a bit tricky, you invert the logic:
jump to "/* do nothing */" in case the char is less than 'A' or bigger than 'Z':

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H  
.DATA
.CODE
MAIN PROC

    MOV AH,1               // get the char
    INT 21H

    CMP AL,'A'             // compare and check what to do
    JB ELSE                // smaller than 'A': don't display it 
    CMP AL,'Z'  
    JA ELSE                // bigger than 'Z': don't display it
THEN:
    MOV AH,2               // you only get here if it's an uppercase letter
    MOV DL,AL
    INT 21H
    // JMP END_IF          // since you're just skipping "do nothing" this jmp 
                           // is not needed at all
ELSE_: 
    /* do nothing */
END_IF:    
    MOV AH,4CH             // exit
    INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Answer (score -1):

Uper/lower case in binary is one bit set or not.

**Example**: 'A' is 65 0x41 and 'a' is 97 0x61 (plus 32)

```
0100 0001 ; A
1100 0001 ; a

1000 0000 ; <--- mask for 'AND' = 0x80 
^--------------- bit tested, if result of AND is zero, UPPER

(....)
AND al, 0x80
cmp al, 0
je upper
  (...) ; code for no upper
  jmp out
upper:
  (...) ; code for upper
out:
```

Comment: That's not where the lower-case bit goes.  It's `0x20` not `0x80`  Also, there are printable ASCII characters that have that bit set which aren't alphabetic, so you still have to range-check after setting or clearing it.  See  [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585515) / [How to access a char array and change lower case letters to upper case, and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936844)  (If you did want to just test+branch on a single bit, `test al, 0x20` / `jz not_lower_maybe_upper`, or use `and`)