# toUpper procedure in MASM?

Tags: assembly, procedure, masm

I am trying to write a trivial toUpper procedure in MASM for ASCII only. It works, however, whenever it encounters a whitespace character, it wont continue changing the case of that character and the ones following it. I can't figure out the reason why this is happening.
So what I did is put a conditional statement to test if a character is a space ' ' (32) and thus jump beyond it. Is this enough or should I test for any value that is not between 97 and 122 also?

```
    ; EDX - INPUT - The offset to the BYTE Array 
    ; ECX - INPUT - The Size of the BYTE Array 
    ; EDX - OUTPUT- The offset to the new BYTE Array toUpper PROC
    PUSH ECX                ; we will modify this so push it to the stack
    DEC  ECX                ; we don't want the null terminating char
    loopMe:         
        MOV  AL, [EDX]      ; otherwise move what the EDX points to to AL       
        CMP  AL, 32         
        JNE  goodChar       
        INC  EDX            ; increment the pointer by one byte since this is a space       
        loop  loopMe        ; go to the next char
        goodChar:           
            AND  AL   , 11011111b  ; make AL capital            
            MOV  [EDX], AL          
            INC  EDX               ; increment the pointer by one byte          
            LOOP loopMe 
    done:
        POP ECX                        ; return it back to its original value
        RET toUpper ENDP
```

Comment: One bug in your code is that if the last character in the string is a space, then you'll fall into the `goodChar` part and execute those instructions. Note also that there's no point in writing ASCII codes directly; the assembler understands `CMP AL, ' '` just fine.

Comment: Only lower case characters should cause the logic to reach `goodChar`. Instead of `CMP  AL, 32` and what comes immediately after, you could do `cmp al, 'a'; jb skip; cmp al,'z'; ja skip`, and then `skip:` would be before the currently second `INC EDX` in your code.

Comment: See [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585515) for a better asm algorithm for checking for alphabetic characters.  See also  [Convert a String In C++ To Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37151084) for the logic and [How to access a char array and change lower case letters to upper case, and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936844) for similar logic in assembly that's more efficient than two separate cmp/jb cmp/ja checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem after the first LOOP instruction:

```
    PUSH ECX
    DEC  ECX
loopMe:         
    MOV  AL, [EDX]
    CMP  AL, 32
    JNE  goodChar
    INC  EDX
    LOOP loopMe
                   <--- what happens here?
    goodChar:
        AND  AL   , 11011111b
        MOV  [EDX], AL
        INC  EDX
        LOOP loopMe
done:
    POP ECX
    RET toUpper
```

There are two solutions here, either jump to the second `LOOP` or jump to the `done:` label after the first loop. Also, you should really only apply the upper "trick" to 'a-z', which means the `CMP AL,...` would test against 'a', if smaller, jump to the loop, then test again against 'z', if larger, jump to the loop.

```
    PUSH ECX
    DEC  ECX
loopMe:         
    MOV  AL, [EDX]
    CMP  AL, 'a'
    JL   next
    CMP  AL, 'z'
    JG   next
    AND  AL   , 11011111b
    MOV  [EDX], AL
next:
    INC  EDX
    LOOP loopMe 
done:
    POP ECX
    RET toUpper
```

Comment: "There are **two** solutions here, either jump to the second LOOP (instruction)..." This would immediately start a 4GB loop! The **only** solution was to jump to the *done:* label.

Comment: @SepRoland What I meant is instead of a first `LOOP ...` it would be to jump to the second `LOOP ...` which is more or less what I show in my fixed sample. I guess there are many other solutions, as the one you propose which is to jump after the `LOOP ...` to the `done:` label.