# Failing to convert upper to lower and vice versa user input string

Tags: assembly, uppercase, lowercase, emu8086

I am trying to write an assembly program on emu8086 to convert upper to lower and vice versa user inputted string but it's not changing any character of the string:

```
.data
```

buffer db 10,?, 10 dup('')

.code

; Read the input

mov ah, 0ah
int 21h

mov si,2

mov ah,0
mov al, [si]

;convert

start:

cmp al, 0

je show

; Lowercase to uppercase

cmp al, 'a'

jl upper

cmp al, 'z'

jg upper

sub al, 32

jmp check

upper:
cmp al, 'A'

jl next_bit

cmp al, 'Z'

jg next_bit

add al, 32

jmp check

check:

mov [si], al
jmp next_bit

;incrementing si register to get the next character

next_bit:
inc si

mov al,[si]

jmp start

;display result

show:
mov si,2

lea dx,si

mov ah, 9

int 21h

jmp end

end:
mov ah, 4ch

int 21h

Comment: The fun way: [How to access a char array and change lower case letters to upper case, and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936844) shows how to efficiently case-flip a character if it's alphabetic, in only 6 instructions per character (starting with `mov` / `or` to make a copy with the lower-case bit set as part of checking for alphabetic, ending with `xor`.)  vs. this way being 12 instructions, more of them compare+branch, not counting the load and store.  But your way is probably correct, the bugs are elsewhere as Jester points out.

Answer (score 1):

1. `mov si, offset buffer` is wrong. The text starts at `buffer+2`.
2. `cmp al, 0` is wrong. Your `buffer` is not zero initialized and you should use the returned byte count anyway.
3. Your code will never convert upper case to lower case since the `; Uppercase to lowercase` block is unreachable.
4. `next_bit` is a misnomer. You probably meant `next_byte`.
5. `lea dx, si` is wrong. You have already incremented `si` to point past the string. You should reload `dx` with `buffer+2`. (Should be a syntax error too.)
6. The text is not terminated by a `$` so int21/09 can not print it as is.
7. `jmp check` is not wrong :) But it's certainly useless jumping to the next line.

Comment: i updated the code above now everything is fine but result is not displaying can you please point me to the problem